# Combination of two conditions in .cs code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

**Desc**

I have a problem with the "where" instruction from the .cs code, I don't know how to use "and" there?

**I tried**

Code dont run, "and" dont exist

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetNumberDays(string mieciacValue, int rokValue)
{
    var liczbaDni = _ecpContext.Miesiace.Where(x => x.Rok == rokValue and x => x.Miesiac == miesiacValue).Select(i => new
    {
         ObecnaIloscDni = i.IloscDni
    });

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the `and` by `&&`. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) for more Details.

eg:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetNumberDays(string mieciacValue, int rokValue)
{
    var liczbaDni = _ecpContext.Miesiace.Where(x => x.Rok == rokValue && x.Miesiac == miesiacValue).Select(i => new
    {
         ObecnaIloscDni = i.IloscDni
    });

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Also remove the second **x =>** as it is not necessary.